# How can I add a new value to an existing column without writing the new value to the table?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the below table1:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | id | feature         | status        |
|------------|----|-----------------|---------------|
| 2019-05-13 | 2  | pricing         | implemented   |
| 2019-05-13 | 2  | pricing         | first_contact |
| 2019-05-13 | 5  | reviews         | implemented   |
| 2019-05-13 | 5  | pricing         | implemented   |
| 2019-05-13 | 6  | reviews         | first_contact |
| 2019-05-13 | 6  | reviews         | implemented   |
| 2019-05-13 | 6  | promotions_geo  | first_contact |
| 2019-05-13 | 6  | prop_management | first_contact |
```

There are two statuses, implemented and first_contact. I want to introduce a third which will be no_contact. This will be the total count of ids minus the sum of ids in implemented and first_contact status.

I can get the total number of ids from a secondary table like so:

```
select
    count(id)
from
    table2
```

So I've tried to union the above so I can get the total count of IDs which can then be subtracted:

```
select
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    feature,
    count(s.id) as implemented_and_first_contact_total,
    null as total_ids
from
    table1 s
where
    s.yyyy_mm_dd = '2020-05-06'
group by
    1,2,4
union all
select
    null as yyyy_mm_dd,
    null as feature,
    null as implemented_and_first_contact_total,
    count(id) as total_ids
from
    table2
```

Now I'm unsure how I can subtract implemented_and_first_contact_total from total_ids in order to get a value for no_contact and have this as a value within status column. Maybe a union isn't correct to use here?

---

Edit: output. Say it turns out there are 300 total ids. The output would look like this:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | feature         | status        | id_count |
|------------|-----------------|---------------|----------|
| 2019-05-13 | pricing         | implemented   | 2        |
| 2019-05-13 | pricing         | first_contact | 1        |
| 2019-05-13 | pricing         | no_contact    | 297      |
| 2019-05-13 | reviews         | implemented   | 2        |
| 2019-05-13 | reviews         | first_contact | 1        |
| 2019-05-13 | reviews         | no_contact    | 297      |
| 2019-05-13 | promotions_geo  | first_contact | 1        |
| 2019-05-13 | promotions_geo  | no_contact    | 299      |
| 2019-05-13 | prop_management | first_contact | 1        |
| 2019-05-13 | prop_management | no_contact    | 299      |
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: I modified the sample data and added example output. I hope it's more clear now

Comment: How would you join table1 to table2? What are the columns present in table2?

Comment: @django-unchained table2 contains meta information. Both tables can be joined via the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select yyyy_mm_dd,
       (count(distinct id) -
        count(distinct case when status in ('implemented', 'first_contact') then id end)
       ) as no_contact
from t
group by yyyy_mm_dd
```

Comment: Kind of. I want the 'no_contact' status to be a value in the 'status' column rather than a new column.

Comment: @stackq . . . Then insert this into your table or use a `union all` query.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Removed uncorrelated subquery from `SELECT` and added `cross join`

Try this:

```
select yyyy_mm_dd, feature, status,
count(id) as id_count
from table1 
group by yyyy_mm_dd, feature, status
union all
select yyyy_mm_dd, feature, 'no_contact' as status, 
(cnt - count(id)) as id_count
from table1 cross join (select count(id) as cnt from table2) 
group by yyyy_mm_dd, feature, cnt;
```

Comment: Not really, they are two different result sets if you see `group by` clause and `id_count`. Did it work for you?

Comment: I mean in your solution, table1 is used twice.

Comment: yeah need to use it because I need to subtract total id count from second table. Please accept answer if it worked for you.

Comment: table1 only contains a subset of the total ids so the count will be incorrect. This is why we need to count the ids from table 2.

Comment: Check the calculation. It's doing what you asked in the question.`((select count(id) from table2) - count(id)) as id_count` this part gets count from `table2`

Comment: It gives an error when run- cannot recognize input near 'select' 'count. I haven't seen two selects before a from before.

Comment: Apparently, Hive doesn't support uncorrelated subqueries in `SELECT` clause.

Comment: This also will not work as Hive is in strict mode so the cartesian product is not allowed